# How to implement AsyncTask in this code.?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

Here is my code. I am trying to extend `AsyncTask` but its not working. Here is my code.
Its showing `NetworkOnMainThread` exception when running My App. I am new to android and I need to develop a login system.

```
    public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject>{
    static InputStream  mInputStream=null;
    static JSONObject mJsonObject=null;
    static String json="";
    String url="";
    List<NameValuePair> params=null;

    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJsonFromURL(String url,List<NameValuePair> params){
        url=this.url;
        params=this.params;
    return doInBackground();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            mInputStream=httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line= null;
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            json=sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mJsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return mJsonObject;
       }
}
```

I dont know is it right way or not.
Please help me.
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
This line shows error for me and dont know how to remove this. Cant apply to String[]

Comment: And where exactly are you extending AsyncTask?

Comment: In my opinion, you need to wrap up your getJsonFromURL function inside an AsyncTask to get the results. The network activity cannot be performed on the main thread, thats why Async task is used. It runs the activity in another thread.

Comment: See my answer some how can help u

Comment: How can i do that?? Shekhar Chikara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a call back interface**

```
public interface CallBack {
    void run(Object result);
}
```

**RequestClient Class**

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    CallBack callBack;

    public RequestClient(CallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //LoginPage.progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String responseString = "";
        HttpClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(LoginPage.url);
            client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 6000);
            client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 6000);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
            if (resEntityGet != null) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return responseString.trim();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callBack.run(result);
        //LoginPage.progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**In the Login Activity**

```
RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(new CallBack() {

            @Override
            public void run(Object result) {
                try {
                    AppResponse = (String) result;

                    String status =ValidateLoginStatus.checkLoginStatus(AppResponse);
                    Log.d("TAG Status recived", status);

                    if (status.equals("300")) {
                        saveInformation(userId, pass);
                        startingActivity();
                    } else {
                        error.setText("Incorrect UserName or Password");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG Exception Occured",
                            "Exception is " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        reqClient.execute(url);
```